# Bonding steel plate to fiber cement sheet effectively

Tags: steel, concrete, reinforced-concrete

I've been trying to produce a cheap panel using fiber cement and zincalume sheet. There is a [research paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0143749682901257) that I read about bonding steel plate to concrete to increase their tensile strength by reaching a fully composite state when they are bonded with epoxy.

I've calculated the cost of bonding those two materials with epoxy and mechanical fasteners. I found out that if I cover the entire surface with epoxy the cost is too high. I wonder can I just make a Square and X shape ( [X] ) with the epoxy adhesive and reach the same benefit as covering the entire surface? Or is there an alternative solution to this?

Comment: Zincalume refers to a galvanic coating on steel. It has poor resistance to the alkaline conditions of Portland ( regular) cement , if any moisture is present.

Comment: @blacksmith37 The bonding process is done after the fiber cement dried up, it is in a sheet form. Shouldn't the moisture problem be less concerning that way?

Comment: Are you mass-producing these units? What kind of quantities are you talking about. If you are doing large scale adhesive bonding you can buy adhesives from chemical suppliers in bulk thereby reducing your costs. By the way, West System G-Flex epoxy is an excellent adhesive for what you are bonding. And no, I do not represent West System in any way, shape or form :-)

Comment: @WilliamHird Yes I'm planning to mass produce these. Maybe 500-1000 panels a month. It is still expensive though...

Comment: OK, then if you want to cheat and use less adhesive you will have to do extensive testing to see if your panels can survive the load(s) they are exposed to without de-laminating.